# pandas: How to access grouped elements one by one after `groupby.x.apply`?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
  "f":["sum", "min", "max"],
  "t":[2, 2, 3]
})
```

so I summarise the `df`

```
df1 = df.groupby("t").f.apply(lambda x:[x])
```

which yields

```
t
2    [[sum, min]]
3         [[max]]
Name: f, dtype: object
```

but how do I refer to the column with data `[[sum,min]], [[max]]`?

I tried

```
for t in df1.index:
  print(df1[t].f)
```

and I was expecting the print out of

```
[[sum,min]]
[[max]]
```

but I just get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'f'
```

How do I refer to columns that I create via `apply` within each group?

Comment: `df1` is already a [pd.Series](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.html) with name `f`. therefore, you don't need to refer to any column since it is already a column. if you use `print(df1[t])` in your for loop, it'll work as you expect

Comment: What are you exactly trying to do, can you explain the idea behind this whole excercise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try:

```
for f in df.groupby('t').f.agg(list):
    print(f)
#out
['sum', 'min']
['max']
```